# No caps lock indicator in tty console

Tags: capslock

I'm unsure if this behavior is normal or not, so I thought I'd ask. My caps lock key works perfectly normally during an X session, but when I log into a virtual console, the indicator light no longer functions, even though the caps lock key itself still works. Is this as it should be?

Comment: It probably depends on your hardware, but as long as it's not some huge, system-crippling issue, you're fine.

Comment: No, it's certainly not a big deal, I'm just stumped. When the laptop powers on the indicator lights up, but then doesn't work unless I start X, and then it works just fine.

Comment: It's probably just some weird driver issue, where the running X session might be holding the keyboard functions. Try stopping any running X session.

Comment: I have my machine set up to boot in text mode, so it does this even before I start up an X session. I guess the drivers for keyboard indicator lights are configured to work with X.

Comment: Probably. There's probably not much you can do, so it's good you don't really care.